# CSS z-index has no effect on the label for an input element

Tags: css, label, z-index

I'd like to use [the checkbox hack](https://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/) to expand a div to show more text. The hack requires the checkbox input to appear first in the DOM, with the elements that it is to affect coming after. I'd like to show the div that is to be expanded behind the label. I had imagined that it would be enough to set the `z-index` of the `label` so that it appears above the `div`:

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" id="more" />
<label for="more">Show more</label>
<div>
    <p>Ipsum lorem and all that jazz</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
input {
    position:absolute;
    clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
    z-index: 999;
}
input + label {
    z-index: 999;
}
input + label::before {
    content:"+";
    padding-right: 0.5em;
    font-family: monospace
}
input:checked + label::before {
    content:"-";
}
input ~ div {
    height: 0;
    padding-top: 1em;
    background: #ffe;
    overflow:hidden;
    position: relative;
    top: -0.4em;
}
input:checked ~ div {
    height: auto;
}
```

However, no value of z-index seems to have any effect. I understand that [there may be different stacking contexts in an HTML page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context). However, I don't see how this affects my simple layout. Removing the `position: absolute` rule for the `input` element does not remove the problem, nor does changing the z-index of the `input` element itself.

What wrong assumptions I am making?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Luk5d6d1/)

---

EDIT: Thanks to @Guy and @taxicala, I've got the demo working: here's an [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Luk5d6d1/2/)

Answer (score 8):

`z-index` is intended for elements positioned as `absolute`, `relative` and `fixed`:

```
input + label {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Currently your `label` is `position: static`, change it to `position: relative` for the z-index to be applied.

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rzssy7hk/)